# HTML5 Audio playing secure url

Tags: javascript, ios, html, audio

We have a book player application that plays narrations. On hitting the page, it has a digest of all of the audio URLs of that book. When you change a page, the audio is supposed to play automatically. On the desktop, this works just fine, whereas on iOS safari, it will not play without direct user interaction. This means that the call stack has to have a user click event, which is okay too, as every page change requires a click.

However, we have recently switched to a CDN that requires signed URLs, which we sign via an ajax call to our site. Because these URLs expire, we have to load the audio assets soon after we get the signed URLs.  So this means, that instead of triggering load / play by changing the page, we are now triggering the URL signing when we change the page. Ideally, the response of the URL signing should be able to trigger the audio play, but, the `onreadystatechange` becomes the root of the call stack. Since this is no longer in the call stack of the `click` event, having audio play on a page is now a *two* step process, which is less than desirable.

As far as I can see it, we have a few options:

- preload all audio when you start the book (this is silly, because this could be hundreds of MB)
- pre-sign all audio, set the expiration to a long time (this is silly, because this essentially circumvents the secure CDN)

Has anybody else had to deal with something like this? How did you get around it? Can anybody see any other options that I'm missing?